# Warum gibt es keinen Artikel in »fährt Boot«?

Tags: article

> Es dämmert noch, aber man sitzt schon am Flussufer und angelt. Die Sonne geht auf, man badet und legt sich in die Sonne, **fährt Boot**.

Warum nicht "fährt Boote" oder "fährt ein Boot"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In dem obigen Zitat handelt es sich um eine feste Wortverbindung eines Nomens mit einem Verb, das hier wie ein Verb benutzt wird (deshalb kein Artikel). Nach [gängigen Regeln](http://canoonet.eu/services/GermanSpelling/Regeln/Getrennt-zusammen/Verb.html?MenuId=SpellingRules020#Anchor-Verbindungen-14210) werden solche Verbindungen nicht zusammengeschrieben, und das Nomen der Verbindung behält die Großschreibung.

> - Ich fahre Auto.
> - Man fährt Boot.

Nur, wenn die Wortverbindung substantiviert ist, wird zusammengeschrieben:

> - Zum Autofahren braucht man einen Führerschein.
> - Im Sommer macht das Bootfahren Spaß.

**Achtung:**

Wenn das Nomen "verblasst" ist, also in der Bedeutung nicht mehr eigenständig stehen kann, muss man das resultierende Kompositum klein schreiben (auch, wenn es dann Teil eines trennbaren Verbs wurde):

> - Wir möchten mit Freunden *eislaufen*.
> - Er gibt seine Geheimnisse preis. (*preisgeben*)
> - Die Welt stand kopf. (*kopfstehen*)

Zu den Regeln siehe:

[Duden](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/getrennt-und-zusammenschreibung#K54)
[Canoo](http://canoonet.eu/services/GermanSpelling/Regeln/Getrennt-zusammen/Verb.html?MenuId=SpellingRules020#Anchor-Verbindungen-14210)

Answer (score 1):

Das ist dieselbe Konstruktion wie

> Jemand fährt Rad.
>   Jemand fährt Bus.
>   Jemand hört Radio.
>   Jemand liest Zeitung.

z.B. in:

> Was machst du für gewöhnlich am Wochenende?
>   Bei schönem Wetter **fahre** ich **Rad,** bei Schlechtwetter bleibe ich daheim und **höre Radio.**
>
> Wie kommst du morgens immer ins Büro?
>   Ich **fahre Bus** und **lese** dabei **Zeitung.**

Answer (score 1):

There is a construct called [Nullartikel](https://web.archive.org/web/20190923003415/http://www.canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Artikel/Gebrauch/Ohne.html), also given in my answer to [this question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/46266/why-mit-karte-has-no-article). A slight problem is, that in all references I looked up, the best matching reason is *Abstrakta*, e.g. Glück, Intelligenz, Musik.

*Boot* in your example does not exactly fit into that category, but what I observe is, that a term used as generic representative also often lacks an article. (The examples given by @Hubert in my opinion do not fall in the category "fixed phrases" suggest in @Takkats answer.)

Examples are:

> - Mit *Karte* zahlen
> - Man trägt wieder *Hut*