# Artikel mit Krankheiten und Symptomen

Tags: difference, article

Ich kann nicht ganz verstehen, wann man einen unbestimmten oder keinen Artikel mit Krankheiten oder Symptomen benutzen muss. Ein deutscher Lehrer und Arzt auf Youtube korrigiert Arztbriefe, die von ausländischen Ärzten geschrieben sind. Beispiele dieser Korrekturen sind:

Der Patient klagt über **eine** Parästhesie.

Der Patient hat **eine** Pencillinallergie/**eine** Pneumonie.

Der Patient litt vor 4 Jahren an **einer** Depression.

Der Patient hat **ein** Engegefühl.

aber,

Der Patient klagt über Schwindelgefühl. (ohne Artikel)

Der Patient berichtet über Hemiparese. (ohne Artikel)

Der Patient berichtet über zweimaliges Erbrechen. (ohne Artikel)

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen diesen Fällen? Ich sehe keinen Unterschied. Ich bin nicht sicher, wann ich einen unbestimmten oder keinen Artikel mit Krankheiten und Symptomen benutzen muss. Es erscheint mir, dass die meisten Nomen Abstrakta sind und deswegen keinen Artikel brauchen wie in zum Beispiel:

Pflanzen brauchen Licht, Wasser und gute Luft.

Energie wird immer teurer.

Comment: Ähnlich zu [Why “Mit Karte” has no article?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/46266/why-mit-karte-has-no-article/46268#46268)

Comment: Ich glaube nicht, dass es hier eine Regel gibt, sondern dass das einfach wissen ist. Dass es "Der Patient klagt über eine Parästhesie." aber "Der Patient berichtet über Hemiparese" heissen soll, ergibt zwar vielleicht aus ärztlicher Sicht irgendeinen Sinn, ich als Laie bin aber froh, wenn ich überhaupt weiß, was die beiden Wörter heißen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es gibt Wörter, die ohne Artikel benutzt werden weil sie nicht begrenzbar sind oder ohne Begrenzung verwendet werden.

Wasser beispielsweise kann begrenzt sein (ein Glas Wasser, wir sprechen dann oft auch von "ein Wasser" beim Bestellen im Restaurant) oder aber als Materie von unbestimmter Grösse ohne Artikel, was dann fast als Kondition wahrgenommen wird: "da ist Wasser und dort ist Leere."

*Parästhesie* war hier wohl lokal gemeint während Hemiparese wohl im ganzen Körper auftritt und somit "allumfassenden" Charakter bekommt.

Adjektive wie in "zweimaliges Erbrechen" können im unbestimmten Fall den Artikel komplett überflüssig machen, z.B. "grosses Interesse", obwohl man einen Artikel noch davor stellen könnte, was dann aber oft seltsam tönt.

Comment: Gute Analyse! Ich brauche keine Regeln, Es reicht mir das Sprachgefuehl zu wissen wie hier in Ihre Analyse.